# Terminology when after inclusion to a RCT patient may undergo two different randomization procedures

Tags: terminology, clinical-trials

I have trouble finding appropriate terminology for the following.

I want to investigate treatments A and B in disease X and treatments C and D in disease Y.

Diseases X and Y are basically two different subtypes of a more vague disease definition.

The problem is that diagnosis of these diseases X and Y can be made only intraoperatively, when patient is heavily sedated. So consent to participate is asked prior to surgery and based on the diagnosis during surgery patient is referred to other of these trials.

What is the terminology for this kind of RCT? It is not a "stratified RCT" or "2-strata RCT" because they refer to different subgroups within treatment group. "2-branch RCT" or "2 armed RCT" doesnt sound right either.

What would be the most appropriate terminology for this kind on study design?